# Show a PopUp when button is clicked if another button is hidden in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a group of buttons, each one of which could be rendered hidden by 'Visible=false' in the code behind file of an aspx page.
One of these buttons is called 'Discussions'

Now, I have another button which should show me a popup when clicked if 'Discussions' is hidden. How do I achieve this using jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this using jQuery. Check the the visibility attribute of the button using .css(). If it's hidden then display a PopUp.

**HTML :**

```
<input type="button" id="popUpButton" value="Show Pop Up" />

<input type="button" id="discussionButton" value="Discussion" />
```

**CSS :**

```
#discussionButton{    
    visibility : hidden;
}
```

**jQuery :**

```
$("#popUpButton").click(function(){
    var visibility = $("#discussionButton").css("visibility");
    if(visibility == "hidden"){
        alert("Discussion Button is Hidden!!");
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/cuUas/)

**Another Way using ASP.NET :**

Use **OnClientClick** attribute of the button to call a function that will check if the button is visible or not with jQuery.

**Markup :**

```
<asp:Button ID="popUpButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="CallFunction()"  Text="Pop Up"/>

<asp:Button ID="discussionButton" runat="server" Text="Discussion" Visible="false" />
```

**jQuery :**

```
function CallFunction() {
    var visibility = $("#discussionButton").is(":visible");
    if (visibility == false) {
        alert("Discussion button is Hidden!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. But we have a few issues here. When asp.net is used to set to control to hidden, the control isn't rendered at all on the html page.
Secondly, I need to know how to add the jquery code to the button using asp.net.

Comment: @DeepanjanNag , I've updated the answer. You can check. Simply check the button's visibility with jQuery on client click. And it's checking the asp.net property.